# Testing a function that has a trigger event

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing a Jasmine Test to test a javascipt function. Following is the function

```
 checkFunc: function (Info1,Info2) {

            if(Info1 && Info2)
            {
                $(document).trigger('customeEvent');
            }

        }
```

I am trying to spy on the custom event that is been triggered. I used spyOnEvent as per some of the resources available in the internet. But as per the official documentation of Jasmine i can't find such a method called spyOnEvent. When i use spyOnEvent it says "spyOnEvent is not defined". Can someone help me how to detect the triggering of this particular event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is listen to the event before triggering it.

```
$(document).on('customEvent', function() {
    testPass(); //Just an example, not sure how to do this in Jasmine
}
```

This is the sort of events that must be handled with a timeout. If the event isn't triggered within a certain time window (again, not sure how Jasmine handles this), the test should fail.